# How to annotate typing.Generic type itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, typing

I was playing around new Python typing system and I faced concept which I don't know how to express in it. I want to pass the generic class type itself. E.g. to describe function which takes generic<sup>[1]</sup> `G`, type `T` and returns `G[T]`.

I used `mypy` to check verify my tries.

### The naive approach didn't work in Python 3.7.

```
from typing import Generic, Type, List, Mapping, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def foo(generic: Generic, param: Type[T]) -> Generic[T]: #  error: Invalid type "typing.Generic"
    return generic[param] #  error: Value of type "Generic?[T?]" is not indexable

ListOfInts: Type = foo(List, int)

assert ListOfInts == List[int] # passes in runtime
```

### Naive GenericMeta in Python 3.6's backport of `typing`?

There is GenericMeta is available in [backport](https://github.com/python/typing), but I didn't find how to use it and it didn't make it to PEP.

```
def foo(generic: GenericMeta, param: Type[T]) -> Type[Type[T]]:
    return generic[param] #  error: Value of type "GenericMeta" is not indexable
```

### Mapping[Type, Type]?

I came up with `Mapping`, but apparently `List` is not such.

```
def apply(generic: Mapping[Type, Type], param: Type[T]) -> Type[Type[T]]:
    return generic[param]

# error: Argument 1 to "apply" has incompatible type "Type[List[Any]]"; expected "Mapping[Type[Any], Type[Any]]"
ListOfInts: Type = apply(List, int)
```

### Less strict works in Python 3.6 and 3.7

This is version I use for now.
It catches some absurd calls like `apply(10, int)`, but `apply(int, int)` will slip through static analysis and raise on runtime.

```
def apply(generic: Type, param: Type[T]) -> Type[Type[T]]:
    return generic[param]
```

So the question comes is it possible to express generic type itself?

As for me, based on duck-typing, `List` should simply be `Mapping[Type, Type]`. I found PEP for [protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544), maybe this is right tool for my problem?

<sup>[1]</sup> If I understand category theory right, such generic's type is technically named [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#Functors_2) and is well known concept in languages like Haskell.